# What is the credentials.txt format used by selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

The README for the project at https://github.com/apurvmishra99/facebook-scraper-selenium includes the instruction:

> Store your email and password for Facebook login in credentials.txt

This project doesn't contain any code that tries to read or parse `credentials.txt`, so I assume that the format has to be standard to selenium or to Python.

What *exactly* is the format this file should be in?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a selenium or python thing. That file was deleted during one of the developer's commits:
[image: deleted github file]

I've had a look for you, and if you look in this file in the project: https://github.com/apurvmishra99/facebook-scraper-selenium/blob/master/fb-scraper/settings.py

You can see it gets the email and password:

```
# User credentials
EMAIL = os.getenv("EMAIL")
PASSWORD = os.getenv("PASSWORD")
```

`os.getenv` is python, [and does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html):

> os.getenv(key, default=None) Return the value of the environment
> variable key if it exists, or default if it doesn’t. key, default and
> the result are str.

What you can try is create environment variables called "EMAIL" and "PASSWORD" set the respectively and then run the main.py

---

Also be aware that in the same settings files the binaries are set as so:

```
# Required binaries
BROWSER_EXE = '/usr/bin/firefox'
GECKODRIVER = '/usr/bin/geckodriver'
FIREFOX_BINARY = FirefoxBinary(BROWSER_EXE)
```

You'll need to ensure these reflect your system.